# how to allow variadic function arguments of unknown types

Tags: typescript

Say I have this code:

```js
interface A {
  doSomething?: <Args extends unknown[]>(...args: Args) => void;
}

type B = {a: {b: {c: string}}};

const a = ({a: {b:{ c}}}: B) => console.log(c);

const AA: A = {
  doSomething: a //Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type '[B]'.
                 //  Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.
}
```

I thought

`doSomething?: <Args extends unknown[]>(...args: Args) => void;`

Would mean the right types would be inferred.

[here is a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnICYD2AygQLYRgAWoA5gPwBcyAPKlDQM7IQAekIeLgFcQAaxAEA7iADaAXQB8ACgB0auOw5M2nAJTIAvAuQA3AsDwBuLAF8sWMAE8ADigBChzHCYYARj4QmDjAoWhtw6ywEAhBg5DhPJQxvTH8MZARwmyY3fSMMmI4CABsIFWKCGiUEXUjo2LA0VG1PbFxCEnIqWiYEgHo+gBUXFAByEXEpWTlR5GAuCUa4Dg5gGhA4X1LkMAIdkeRRmTcZlRxcC8ur3AHcQY0aCmQoCABHIWAXrgBGblLycBKDj6XxCRpFIRQJDIUhwRzIShwEwoGAQSTQM42IA) with the above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```js
interface A {
  doSomething?: (...args: any[]) => void;
}

type B = {a: {b: {c: string}}};

const a = ({a: {b:{ c}}}: B) => console.log(c);

const AA: A = {
  doSomething: a //Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type '[B]'.
                 //  Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.
}
```

You can also consider to use the generic typings like the following:

```
interface A<T> {
  doSomething?: (...args: T[]) => void;
}

type B = {a: {b: {c: string}}};

const a = ({a: {b:{ c}}}: B) => console.log(c);

const AA: A<B> = {
  doSomething: a //Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type '[B]'.
                 //  Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.
}
```